# For what functions does this inequality hold?

Tags: functions, inequality

I would like to know for what kind of functions, the inequality
$$\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}\leq \frac{1}{b-a}$$
hold for all $x\in[a,b]$. $f^\prime(x)$ is derivative w.r.t. $x$.

Is there some general rule? (E.g. $f(x)$ must be convex, etc.) Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Maybe an "inverse" question. For which functions does it never hold?

Answer (score 1):

It depends heavily on $b-a$. If $b-a$ is very large, then you are demanding that $f(x)$ must be *much larger* than $f'(x)$, while if $b-a$ is small, there is hardly any demand, appart from the fact that, obviously, $f$ must have no roots on $[a,b]$.

Nothing in your question, however, demands that the functions need to be convex or concave. In fact, for every function $f$, the function $g(x) = f(x) + M$ will satisfy your inequality for some large enough value of $M$.

Comment: But it only has to hold for $x\in [a,b]$ so if $b-a$ is small it has to hold for fewer values of $x$....

Comment: @JPi Yes, exactly. I am interested only in functions with domain $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Jpi sure, you are correct, but I don't see your point. It still holds that convex, concave and other functions can satisfy the demand written.

Comment: I was thinking about using the Mean value theorem, but I can't come up with anything reasonable,i.e.,
$f^\prime(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

Comment: Mean value theorem here won't help you, unfortunately.

Comment: @5xum Really? I see very strong resemblance with MVT.

Comment: @pisoir on the surface, maybe, but there are a lot of differences, MVT tells you that *some* value $x$ exists so that $(b-a)f'(x) = f(b) - f(a)$, meaning that, sure, $\frac{f'(x)}{f(b)-f(a)} = \frac{1}{b-a}$, but you can't replace $f(b)-f(a)$ with $f(x)$, and neither can you say in which way the inequality is pointing for other values of $x$...

Comment: @5xum Here is my thinking:

From MVT $\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{f(x)(b-a)}$, which we want to bound, i.e., $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{f(x)}\leq 1$, which leads to $f(b)-f(a)\leq f(x)$..Doesn't it mean that $f(x)$ must be decreasing ($a<b$)?

Comment: Please try to read my answers. I have already proven to you that $f$ does not need to be decreasing or increasing, since the inequality you want to show holds for any function which is large enough (be it decreasing, increasing or some of both). Anyway, how did you get $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{f(x)}\leq 1$ from $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{f(x)(b-a)}$?

Comment: For $x\in[a,b]$, $\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{f(x)(b-a)}\leq\frac{1}{b-a}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{f(x)}\leq 1$

Comment: Ah, now I see. Yes, you have that, meaning that there *exists* such a value $x$ that $f(x) \geq f(b)-f(a)$, and you can only conclude that if $f(x) > 0$, otherwise the inequality is reversed. And again, that only holds for *one* value of $x$, it tells you nothing of the function in general.

Comment: @5xum Ok,I understand. Thanks.